# How to insert multiple rows from a single row in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the following table in an Oracle database

```
src_tbl
id     from_date      thru_date
------------------------------
1      01-JAN-2015    31-oct-2016
2      01-APR-2016    31-DEC-2015
3      01-JUL-2014    31-DEC-2016
```

I would like to insert rows from src_tbl into a target table and create a
row for each month between from_date and thru_date like this:

```
tgt_tbl
--------------------------
id           month
1            JAN-2015
1            FEB-2015
1            MAR-2015
...
...
2            APR-2016
2            MAY-2016
2            JUN-2016            
...
...
3            JUL-2014
3            AUG-2014
3            SEP-2014
3            OCT-2014
...
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One hopes your two date columns are actually `DATE` data type, and not strings... are they?

Comment: 2015 in the `thru_date` for `id = 2` is a typo, correct? You should have a check constraint to make sure that the `thru_date` is never earlier than the `from_date`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select     id, to_char( add_months(from_date, level - 1), 'MON-yyyy' ) as mth
from       src_tbl
connect by level <= months_between(thru_date + 1, from_date)
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

**Note**: As discussed in comments, I assumed the "environment" guarantees that `thru_date` is never earlier than `from_date` for any `id`. If it is, this query will produce a row (for the `from_date` month) when perhaps it should produce none. Ideally that logical condition is enforced by a check constraint on the base table.

Comment: Nice solution for valid data, but for the given input the ID = 2 should IMO return no record as thru_date <  from date

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - I noticed that and in my test I changed the second line to be valid. I agree with your point, but I would suggest that the data model should be so that `thru_date >= from_date` is a constraint in the table (rather than having to code around violations of that condition).

Answer (score 0):

here is the SQL SERVER version. you can sure find Oracle CTE syntax.
but the recursion logic remains same.

```
    create table tbl1(id int, fd date, td date)
    insert into tbl1(id,fd,td)
              Select 1,'1-1-2016','4-1-2016'
    union all select 2,'6-1-2016','8-1-2016'



     ;with c1(fd,td,id,rowid)
     AS
     (
        select fd,td,id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rowid from tbl1
     ),
     c2(fd,td,id,rowid)
     AS
     (
        select fd,td,id,rowid from c1-- where rowid=1
        union all
        select DATEADD(month,1,c2.fd),c1.td,c1.id,c2.rowid from c1
        join c2 on c2.fd<c1.td and c1.id=c2.id
     )
     select * from c2 order by rowid,fd
```

[image]